# IEnumerables behaving different when deleting Items from them in a For Each loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, foreach, ienumerable

It is commonly known that removing items from an `IEnumerable` inside a For Each loop iterating over it is a really bad idea. I always thought that `IEnumerable` would throw an exception when you still try to do it.
However I noticed that [`List`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`TreeNodeCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) don't behave the same way, even though they both implement `IList`, `ICollection` and `IEnumerable`.

`List` behaves as I expected. The following code throws an `InvalidOperationException`:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)

list.Add("Entry 1")
list.Add("Entry 2")
list.Add("Entry 3")
list.Add("Entry 4")
list.Add("Entry 5")

For Each entry As String In list
    list.Remove(entry)
Next
```

but `TreeNodeCollection` doesn't throw an exception in .NET 2 and deletes some of the Items, in .NET 4.5.2 the snippet throws a `NullReferenceException`:

```
Dim tree As New TreeView
Dim root As TreeNode = tree.Nodes.Add("Root")
root.Nodes.Add("Node 1")
root.Nodes.Add("Node 2")
root.Nodes.Add("Node 3")
root.Nodes.Add("Node 4")
root.Nodes.Add("Node 5")

For Each node As TreeNode In root.Nodes
    root.Nodes.Remove(node)
Next
```

Why is there such a different behaviour between two `IEnumerable`s?

Comment: I think your question is slightly oddly phrased since the `IEnumerable` interface offers *no* ability to modify what is being enumerated. It seems odd, therefore, to focus on that interface when you're actually interested in modifications.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I don't really get why it is odd. I would be happy if you edit it with better wording

Comment: Why not just Clear()

Comment: @Paparazzi because these codes should only demonstrate the differences. In my application where I had problems with removing nodes from a tree, I only wanted to delete some nodes, not all

Comment: Modify a collection while enumerating is a problem.  Don't do it.

Comment: @Paparazzi thank you, but I don't think "Don't change a collection while enumerating it" is the solution for "You shouldn't change a collection while enumerating it. But why do some collections behave different when trying?"

Comment: Yes an unsupported action may behave differently.  What is the point?

Comment: I always assumed there was a defined or recommended behaviour, because I always observed the same behaviour so far. Thinking there would be such a "normal" behaviour I wondered why TreeNodeCollection has a different behaviour. Hence the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IEnumerable` interface doesn't have anything, either technically or via documentation, to say about *modifications*. There is nothing contractual that requires a collection that implements the interface to throw an exception if they are modified during enumeration.

It may be that some collections are perfectly capable of continuing enumeration even after modification. I.e. what they enumerate may be "the contents of the collection as it was when enumeration started", or they may offer some other guarantees about items which are added or removed after enumeration starts.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, if you want to remove items you should make a copy first:

```
For Each entry As String In list.ToList()
    list.Remove(entry)
Next
```

Other options include:

- Using a backwards For loop. `For i = list.Count-1 To 0 Step - 1`
- Use LINQ to make a new list. `list = list.Where(...).ToList`